# How to change height of NextJS Image tag according to screen width?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, media-queries, next-images

I am using next/image to render my image like this:

```
<Image 
 src={imageLink} 
 width="1920" 
 height="512" 
 alt="Hero Image" 
/>
```

This is fine for screen widths above 750px.

How to update the height to "612" when the user visits on mobile or tablet (below 750px screen width)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put Image inside div and put the following props on the Image:

```
<div className="div-class">
   <Image src={imageLink} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
</div>
```

The div in this example needs to have `position: relative`. Now you will be able to give this div any height/width you need with media queries

Answer (score 6):

In 2023 and with NextJS 13, the `Image`-API has changed. Working with the new app directory and new naming-convention of NextJS 13, this is what I did to accomplish requested behavior:

```
// page.jsx

import styles from './page.module.css';
import logo from '../public/logo.png';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.logoContainer}>
      <Image src={logo} alt='Argo Logo' fill />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
/* page.module.css */

.logoContainer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 158.57px;
  height: 30.93px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .logoContainer {
    width: 79.285px;
    height: 15.465px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

put your Image inside div like this and you can change height and width now

```
 <div className='relative h-96 md:h-3/4'>
     <Image className='h-full sm:h-64' 
         src="/static/images/desktop/image-header.jpg" alt="sun" 
         layout='fill' objectFit='cover' width={400} height={350} />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the latest Next.js, you can use responsive size for images. Example is given below:

```
<Image
    fill
    src="/example.png"
    sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw,  1920px"
  />
```

Note: **sizes** will change the width of the image. For changing the height of the image wrap the image inside of a ***div*** and use CSS to change the height of the parent division.

For documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#sizes

Answer (score 1):

You create a `css class` (in your `custom.css` or anywhere)

Then you define `props` you need (height, styling etc)

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .custom_class {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .custom_class {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .custom_class {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .custom_class {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Grid tag as a parent while using Image TAG. See Example below

```
 <Grid width={30}>
       <Image
         onClick={() => setIsDrawerOpen(true)}
         layout="responsive"
         src={menuIcon}
         component="img"
         alt="Whatsapp logo">
         </Image>
 </Grid>
```